# Cypress: Get all elements containing a given string / regex

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to test a pagination bar with cypress.

I want to assert the number of buttons containing a number only in this bar, and ignore the other buttons (previous page, next page...)

The buttons are looking like this:

```
<button class="...">33</button>
```

I first tried this test:

```
cy.get('.pagination')
  .find('button')
  .contains(/\d+/)
  .should('have.length.gte', 2)
```

But this gave me a warning about the fact that contains will only return one element, making the "length" test useless.

I also tried many combinations based on filter, the ":contains" jquery keyword, but none worked:

```
.filter(`:contains('/\d+\')`) 
// >> finds nothing

.filter((elt) => { return elt.contains(rx) })  
// >> throws 'elt.contains is not a function'

.filter((elt) => { return rx.test(elt.text()) }) 
// >> throws 'elt.text is not a function'

.filter(() => { return rx.test(Cypress.$(this).text()) }) 
// filter everything and return nothing, even the buttons containing the text '1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.filter()` with a callback has parameters `(index, elt) => {}` which means you can use it like this

```js
cy.get('.pagination')
  .find('button')
  .filter((index, elt) => { return elt.innerText.match(/\d+/) }) 
  .should('have.length.gte', 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`nextAll()` fails if there's element wrapping the buttons, but you can count the wrappers.

```js
cy.get('.pagination')
  .find('button')     // presume this is 'Prev' button
  .parent()
  .nextAll(':not(:contains(Next))')
  .should('have.length.gte', 2)
```

or `.nextUntil()`

```js
cy.get('.pagination')
  .find('button')     // presume this is 'Prev' button
  .parent()
  .nextUntil(':contains(Next)')
  .should('have.length.gte', 2)
```

or `.children()`

```js
cy.get('.pagination')
  .children(':not(:contains(Prev)):not(:contains(Next))')
  .should('have.length.gte', 2)
```

Overall, `.filter()` is better as it does not assume the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

[`nextAll()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/nextall) might work in this situation:

```js
cy
  .get('.pagination')
  .find('button')
  .contains(/\d+/)
  .nextAll()
  .should('have.length.gte', 2);
```

Another solution might be to distinguish the pagination buttons by something else, like a class, or some html attribute that is unique to them.

Comment: Thanks, but the nextAll method does'nt do it. I'm currently using a class to identify those buttons, but this does'nt really goes along with the philosophy of end-to-end tests, as it is prefered to interact with the page like a user would do, looking for labels and icons, not for ids or classes, that's why I hoped to filter those buttons by caption and not by class

Answer (score 1):

You can use an loop through the elements and match the element text and then increment a count variable and then later validate it, something like:

```js
var count =0
  cy.get('.pagination').find('button').each(($ele) => {
  if(/\d+/.test($ele.text()){
    count++
  }
})
expect(count).to.be.greaterThan(2)
```

You can do other things as well like:

1. Assertions

```js
cy.get('.pagination').find('button').each(($ele) => {
  if(/\d+/.test($ele.text()){
    expect(+$ele.text().trim()).to.be.a('number')
  }
})
```

2. Perform Click

```js
cy.get('.pagination').find('button').each(($ele) => {
  if(/\d+/.test($ele.text()){
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
  }
})
```

3. Validate Inner text

```js
cy.get('.pagination').find('button').each(($ele) => {
  if(/\d+/.test($ele.text()){
    cy.wrap($ele).should('have.text', 'sometext')
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to something we could generalize to other situations, not only for counting, but maybe to interact with or make assertions over

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can have a look, if any of them could help you in your use case.

Comment: I'll look into it, maybe by substituting a callback to the inner function, and putting it in a `Cypress.Commands.add(...)` statement, we could create such a filter. The `wrap()` method was something I was missing too, thanks.